# multistore with (some) wrong urls

Tags: cart, multistore

newbie here. We did setup a multistore in magento, look this way: a main store contains 2 child stores.

mainstore.mydomain.com
store1.mydomain.com
store2.mydomain.com

now the weird part: I run through the products, everything is fine produt1 belongs to store 1 and I see it only there, which is exactly what I need. The problem is if I order it, then in the cart the product url doesn't point to the store 1 but to the mainstore, which I don't want. How do I make it point to his own store?

Thanks a lot

Comment: have you reindex after creating stores ?

Comment: yes I did, no solution yet.